# How can I create a drop down selector that shows 1H (first half of year) and 2H (second half of year) check boxes?

Tags: looker-studio

I would like to have a drop down check box selector that gives me the option to select all activities in 1H (first half of year) or 2H (second half of year). The Date is currently defaulted to the standard date control drop down.

1H = January 1st - June 30th
2H = July 1st - December 31st

The current field name being used for the default date selector is titled "Requests" and uses the format (YYYYMMDD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create following field with the formula:

```
if(EXTRACT(MONTH from potz)<7,"1H","2H")
```

Use that field in a drop down box.

The data range in the standard date control drop down has to be selected correctly. If you doubt your users, do a drop down for the year as well.